# Prevent click in dropdown container to close dropdown

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I need to make a single type of dropdown (so the same class) that has multiple instances in same page. Each must work properly, on click expand content, on click inside content keep it showing (including login/register forms, dropdowns, checkbox etc or even blank area), on click outside of dropdown - close it and olso close it if i click on it's title or another dropdown.
I managed to do most of what i need except the fact that it closes when i use checkbox or input fields - any click inside dropdown content will close it. I have see that i must use e.preventDefault(); but when i tried, it prevented the dropdown from opening.

I have made a jsfiddle so you can see it live and tell me what i did wrong or miss.

```js
$(".dropdown").click(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  $(this).parent().find(".dropdown").not(this).find(".dropdown-values").slideUp();
  $(this).find(".dropdown-values").slideToggle();
});
$(document).click(function(event) {
  $(".dropdown-values").slideUp();
});
```

```css
.dropdown-container {
  background: #ddd;
}

.dropdown {
  background: #313654;
  display: inline-block;
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
  border-right: 1px solid #3f4c6b;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown:hover {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}

.dropdown-title {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFF;
}

.dropdown-values {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 100%;
  background: #3f4c6b;
  padding: 15px;
  display: none;
}

.dropdown-values a:HOVER {
  background: #dedede;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown-container">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-title">Login</a>
    <div class="dropdown-values">
      <a class="dropdown-link" href="/test1">MY STORY</a>
      <a class="dropdown-link" href="/test2">MY STYLE</a>
      <a class="dropdown-link" href="/test3">MY STYLE X</a>
      <a class="dropdown-link" href="/test4">MY STYLE Y</a>
      <form method="post" action="index.html">
        <p>
          <input type="text" name="login" value="" placeholder="Username or Email">
        </p>
        <p>
          <input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password">
        </p>
        <p class="remember_me">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="remember_me" id="remember_me"> Remember me on this computer
          </label>
        </p>
        <p class="submit">
          <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Login">
        </p>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-title">Register</a>
    <div class="dropdown-values">
      <div class="dropdown-value">
        <a class="dropdown-value" href="/test5">MY PRICING</a>
      </div>
      <div class="">
        <a class="dropdown-value" href="/test6">SERVICES</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should bind the dropdown click trigger only to 'dropdown-title'. Replace all the JS part with this:

```
$(".dropdown-title").click(function(event) {
  $(this).siblings(".dropdown-values").slideToggle();
});
$(".dropdown").mouseleave(function(event) {
  $(".dropdown-values").slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: Click inside dropdown is ok but i lose close when i click anywhere on the page + click on another dropdown. When a dropdown is expanded and i click on another, the first one must close, as it happens in my original jsfiddle.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to handle that one. But check out my edited snippets.

Comment: Not working properly. Check the new jsfiddle that i have added with all things working properly and check with your jquery. In your solution, the moment i hover from Service to About, the dropdowns start to show one or both in same time. Once i have one opened and i click outside (in the page), to have it closed, nothing happens. It would be nice to have the same functionality as in my solution but with a shorter (cleaner) jquery.

Answer (score 0):

This is the working solution - i have added olso other forms inside dropdown.

```js
  $(".dropdown").click(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  $(this).parent().find(".dropdown").not(this).find(".dropdown-values").fadeOut(500);
  $(this).parent().find(".dropdown").not(this).find(".dropdown-title").removeClass("activated");
});
$(document).click(function(event) {
  $(".dropdown-values").fadeOut(500);
  $(".dropdown-title").removeClass("activated");
});
$(".dropdown-title").click(function(event) {
  $(this).siblings(".dropdown-values").fadeToggle(500);
  $(this).parents(".dropdown").find('.dropdown-title').toggleClass("activated");
});
```

```css
 .activated {
   background: red;
 }
.dropdown-container {
  background: #ddd;
}
.dropdown {
  background: #313654;
  display: inline-block;
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
  border-right: 1px solid #3f4c6b;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.dropdown:hover {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}
.dropdown-title {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFF;
}
.dropdown-values {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 100%;
  background: #3f4c6b;
  padding: 15px;
  display: none;
}
.dropdown-values a {
  display: block;
}
.dropdown-values a:HOVER {
  background: #dedede;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown-container">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-title">ABOUT</a>
    <div class="dropdown-values">
      <select name="cars">
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
      </select>
      <form>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked>Male
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other">Other
      </form>
      <a class="dropdown-link" href="/test1">MY STORY</a>
      <a class="dropdown-link" href="/test2">MY STYLE</a>
      <a class="dropdown-link" href="/test3">MY STYLE X</a>
      <a class="dropdown-link" href="/test4">MY STYLE Y</a>
      <form method="post" action="index.html">
        <p>
          <input type="text" name="login" value="" placeholder="Username or Email">
        </p>
        <p>
          <input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password">
        </p>
        <p class="remember_me">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="remember_me" id="remember_me">Remember me on this computer
          </label>
        </p>
        <p class="submit">
          <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Login">
        </p>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-title">SERVICE</a>
    <div class="dropdown-values">
      <div class="dropdown-value">
        <a class="dropdown-value" href="/test5">MY PRICING</a>
      </div>
      <div class="">
        <a class="dropdown-value" href="/test6">SERVICES</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```